# Can't get access token for custom AD Application

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

When attempting to get an access token for a custom AD Application, using `az account get-access-token --resource '<APP ID Uri>'`, I receive the following error:

`AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46' named 'Microsoft Azure CLI'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.`

`04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46` is not my application id, and my application has had administrator consent granted. I've tried putting this id in an interactive login request with no change in behavior.

`get-access-token` works fine when the resource is a defined MS endpoint like `https://database.windows.net` or `https://vault.azure.net/`

My goal is to have Azure App Services with Managed Service Identity authenticating to each other with short-lived AD bearer tokens. Each service has a configured audience that corresponds to the AD App.

Comment: not sure what the command is for cmd line but in powershell it is 'New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId <ObjectID> -Scope '/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID> -RoleDefinitionName contributor' Basically it's telling you to give the object contributor rights. I haven't figured out how to create a new application without having to perform this step and haven't seen any documentation requiring it either. That's what works though.

Comment: I get a null reference from this - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I finally found what I was looking for. If you go into your subscription and open the IAM blade choose your <AD application>, then under "Manage" choose "Properties". There is the "ObjectID" you are referencing. If that does not match the <04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46> id you aren't using the correct application to log in.

Comment: that 04b id is Azure CLI. I don't know how to change it, is the problem.

Comment: You don't change it. That is the objectID for the AD application and needs to be granted contributor role.

Comment: This sounds like the issue at [[BUG] Unable to get MSI token from local Visual Studio](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/6172).

Answer (score 21):

Running `az account get-access-token --resource '<APP ID Uri>'` from local CLI, you are trying to get token from `'<APP ID Uri>'` using Azure CLI, which client ID is exactly `04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46`.

To handle this you could go to:
**Azure Active Directory → App registrations → {your app} → Expose an API → Add client application with**:

> **ID**: `04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46`
>
> **Authorized scopes**: check `'<APP ID Uri>'`

To make sure you have right ID you could run `az account get-access-token` paste token to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and find value of `"appid"`.

Documentation reference:
[Application IDs for commonly used Microsoft applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/verify-first-party-apps-sign-in#application-ids-for-commonly-used-microsoft-applications)

Comment: That really helped me out. I was kind of in a similar situation, except my issue was with the Powershell Azure ID : 1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2 . That being said, I applied your solution and it worked great :)

Comment: Thanks, this answer is really helpful for me.

To some one who cannot find {your app}, you might get the same error message from kubectl that does not tell you what is {your app}. But kubectl will ask you to run this command "az login --scope xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/.defualt"
I would like to tell you that "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" is your app ID of {your app} that you need to find in "Azure Active Directory → App registrations"

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue with a `--resource '<APP ID Uri>'`,  if I login cli with a user account.

[image]

If I login with a service principal, it works fine.

[image]

You could try to login azure cli with a service principal, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#sign-in-with-a-service-principal).

Comment: This is a very helpful workaround, thank you. I am still hoping to find a way to allow users to receive access tokens as themselves, since part of the reason we're doing this is to avoid passing around login credentials.

Comment: Maybe I missed a detail, but if you are using a AD application, you should be using service principal. Not a user account.

Comment: I'm trying to develop locally, and I cannot get the azure cli to pull the access-token for an AD application for my user login in my local web application. 

I did login as a service principal though and was able to pull the token while debugging locally.  I'm not sure why it doesn't work for user accounts which have been granted default access to the AD application.